# Hide browser loading icon on iframe reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, iframe

I am trying to make an iframe reload every 1 second but when it does it shows the [spinning loader on the browser tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hL9rA.png). Is it possible to make the iframe reload without letting the browser notice the reload. Could Jquery or Ajax do the job?

```
function do_reload(){
    document.title = "Title";
    document.getElementById('iframe_box').src='status.php'
    document.title = "Title";
}

window.setInterval("do_reload()", 1000);
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgaec6cj/)**

Comment: I highly doubt it since that icon is usually displayed simply because the browser or tab is doing something... Even if its performing an ajax request, at least in my experience...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes jquery and ajax can do it.** 
using jquery load method, example shown below 
suppose you have div with id = "window" then use following jquery

```
    function loadWindow()
    {
      $("#window").load("status.php");
    }
```

then call this every 1 second.. window.setInterval(loadWindow,1000);

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you meant by that, heres a JSFiddle of the code in JQuery http://jsfiddle.net/rhdo86t2/ but not using load instead attr what do you suppose for me to change.

Comment: what i meant is, make a div with width and height you like.then using jquery load method, async load submit.php to that div. This will hide browser loading icon. Still if you dont understand, i can explain :)

Comment: step 1, create a div instead of iframe. then give id for that div(example- id="frame")

step 2
create a function and inside that function, call jquery load method and display submit.php to div with id="frame"
function loadWindow()
    {
      $("#window").load("status.php");
    }

now call this function every 1 sec automatically...

Comment: Although that will load status.php async to the div, since its load doesnt the function only occur when the page loads? [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/rhdo86t2/1/)

Comment: the function occurs every 1second, not on page loads :) so that works!!
i have one suggestion, please increase 1second time gap to 10 second or more, because a webpage needs sometime to load async :)

Comment: yes almost...but change <div id="window" src="http://www.w3schools.com/php/demo_func_time.php"></div> to <div id="window"></div>

Comment: and always remember, this works if submit.php is in same server domain. cross-domain wont work i think! hope you are satisfied with my answer :) vote up if yes :) thanks

Comment: Wow your method it worked like a charm on my localhost. Thanks you!